# rewrite redshift query as athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to convert this redshift query to athena.

```
  select
    a.customerid,
    a.country,
    a.stockcode,
    a.description,
    a.invoicedate,
    a.sales_amt,
    (b.nbr_months_active) as nbr_months_active
  from
    ecommerce_sales_data a
    inner join (
      select
        customerid,
        count(
          distinct(
            DATE_PART(y, cast(invoicedate as date)) || '-' || LPAD(
              DATE_PART(mon, cast(invoicedate as date)),
              2,
              '00'
            )
          )
        ) as nbr_months_active
      from
        ecommerce_sales_data
      group by
        1
    ) b on a.customerid = b.customerid
```

This is what I have tried. It returns the results. But I am not sure if the results will match with redshift query in all cases.

```
WITH students_results(InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country) AS (VALUES
('536365','85123A','WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER','6','12/1/2010 8:26','2.55','17850','United Kingdom'),
('536365','71053','WHITE METAL LANTERN','6','12/1/2010 8:26','3.39','17850','United Kingdom'),
('536365','84406B','CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER','8','12/1/2010 8:26','2.75','17850','United Kingdom')
)
  select
    a.customerid,
    a.country,
    a.stockcode,
    a.description,
    a.invoicedate,
     cast(a.quantity as decimal(11,2)) * cast(a.unitprice as decimal(11,2)) as sales_amt,
    (b.nbr_months_active) as nbr_months_active
  from
    students_results a
    inner join (
      select
        customerid,
        count(
          distinct(
date_format(date_parse(invoicedate,'%m/%d/%Y %k:%i'), '%Y-%m')
        )) as nbr_months_active
FROM students_results group by customerid) as b
on a.customerid = b.customerid
```

The source of Redshift query is here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-multi-class-classification-models-with-amazon-redshift-ml/